# Laravel - Same model related through another

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm having trouble finding the appropriate documentation on this.

I'm have a `User` model, each `User` can have a many to many relationship with a `Site`. I am trying to find out how to get the relationships between `User`s.

For example, one `User` might be the `Site` owner, and the other could be the `Client`. If I have the owner object, how can I retrieve an array of `Client`s, associated with all, or individual `Site`s.

I've tried using

```
public function clients() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('User', 'Site');
}
```

However this still returns the current user which I'm unable to filter out.

I'm not sure if I have my models wrong, e.g. needing to have an Owner and a Client model, which both extend a generic User.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know if a User is an owner or a client? Do you store that information in the User table? However I'm not sure if the `hasManyThrough` method is appropriate here, after all you don't have an intermediate relation. I'd rather use `belongsToMany` as described here: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your models are probably fine. You are using many-to-many relation, so good place for specifying the type of that relation would be that same table - pivot table.

```
users
  id
  name

sites
  id
  url

site_user
  site_id
  user_id
  type
```

where type is for example string *owner* or *client*.

```
class User extends Eloquent {
  public function sites() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Site')
                ->withPivot('type');
  }
}
class Site extends Eloquent {
  public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User')
                ->withPivot('type');
  }
  // you can use something like this 
  public function clients(){
    return $this->users()->wherePivot('type', 'client');
  }
}
```

Once you have the site you want, you can then get clients like this

```
$clients = $site->clients()->get();
```

hope this get you in right direction (away from creating more models, trying to figure out inheritance, dealing with the Factory pattern etc... ). sometimes solutions are simple, and from my experience - when you start to over-complicate the models (in this manner), there is a good chance that something is wrong with your database design.

Comment: This looks exactly what I need, one quick question, how do I specify the type when saving the associations? Thanks

Comment: $user->sites()->attach($site_id, array('type'=>'client'));